Get a steady green flame
For a scientific demonstration, I am interested in making and maintaining a green flame. I have solid copper sulfate pentahydrate (CSP) for the color. I tried several methods, all of which failed:

Placing the solid CSP in a bowl with liquid diesel fuel and lighting it up.
Dissolving the CSP in water, adding it to the liquid diesel in a
bowl, stirring it, and lighting it up.
Dissolving the CSP in water, mixing it with liquid isopropanol (70%) in a bowl, stirring it, and lighting it up.

In all cases, I got a flame of "normal color" (yellowish). The flame was green only when I blew on it. Could you please share with me why my attempts failed and advise me on what I should do to get a steady green flame?

By 'igniting it', do you mean you placed the mixture in a bowl and then lit the liquid up? Or do you mean you sprayed the mixture through a flame? Or...? And what do you mean by 'puffed it'?

@isolatedmatrix thank you for your comments, I edited my post.


The bright yellow color of a sooty flame (from burning carbon particles) covers the green. Don't use diesel fuel. 2. CuSO4 does not dissolve well in alcohol. Try boric acid, instead.


Don't you have a burner for your "scientific demonstration"? Just make a paste of the CSP with HCl and take a platinum or nichrome wire dip it in the paste and introduce it in the flames.

Boron compounds are usually a far better bet for generating green flames. Boric acid and methanol works well as methanol burns cleanly without producing a lot of particulate carbon which glows yellow, masking the flame colour when fuels like diesel are burned.

Thank you all for your help! I don't have a burner. I just bought boric acid, I will try to dissolve it in the alcoholic fuels I have when it arrives.

Copper is a bad choice for green flame, especially sulfate. It is best suited for blueish flames in presence of large amount of halogen, like in (NH4)2CuCl4 you can obtain by evaporation of water from solution of individual chlorides. Green can be obtained using boron (boric acid in methanol), but pirotechnic compositions usually use barium salts (nitrate, chlorate).

I second Dr. Moishe Pippik's and Matt Black's comments. Whether using a copper salt or a boron compound, a less carbon-rich, cleaner-burning fuel than diesel is an asset. I recall from my school days that flame tests are often done with a Bunsen flame or something similar, burning natural gas/methane.
Boric acid is "soluble in lower alcohols", which are probably the alcohols used as fuels. So the boric acid approach should work. Possibly you may make a comparison between burning the alcohol with the boric acid versus without. Even if the alcohol colors the flame you may see a color difference. Methanol is recommended for the alcohol because it is the least carbon-rich and cleanest-burning alcohol.

Note that using methanol in the boric acid case is essential to get clean green. Ethanol adds significant amount of yellow, with clearer green mainly at the flame ends (IIRC). There is usually added few drops of H2SO4 to catalyze formation of volatile esters (RO)3B.

P.S. Or perhaps opposite, green flames with yellow ends. It was many years ago.
